# Stitching 2 boundaries together

Tags: computational-geometry, mesh, geometry

Let us say we have 2 boundaries of 2 meshes that are roughly aligned, for example 2 generalized cylinders (sweeping surfaces) with a small gap in between. And let us say we want to connect them to each other.

The 2 don't necessarily have the same number of points. Is there an algorithm to find a triangulation of the space between the 2 boundaries?

[image]

Somtehing like this image, where we find connections between the boundaries such that the resulting graph forms a well behaved watertight manifold connecting the 2.

Comment: do you know which vertices should be connection vertices? Or should the algorithm find it out itself?

Comment: The algorithm needs to find out. If I knew there would be no need to ask this :p

Comment: Will the boundaries each be planar, convex polygons, or more general than that?

Comment: Neither co planar nor convex